# I can't save the PDF on with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to download a PDF, however it takes a screenshot of the screen and does not save the document in a normal PDF.

I am using Python 3.8 and Selenium.

The image comes out like this:

[image]

My code:

```
import json
from selenium import webdriver

prefs ={ "recentDestinations": [{
                  "id": "Save as PDF",
                  "origin": "location",
                  "account": "", # <======= Add this
             }],
             "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
             "version": 2,
            "margin": 0,
            'size': 'auto'
}


profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(prefs),
           'savefile.default_directory': 'D:\Documents\PycharmProjects\projects\Manipule_PDF'}

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile, )
chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\Documents\chrome\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Does anyone know how to save the entire PDF??

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Send URL which you are using in `driver.get(url)` so that I can check entire flow of your code locally on my computer.

Comment: you should add the URL otherwise we can't figure it out.

Comment: URL contains personal data.